# Eclipse crashes on pressing . (period) button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently learning Android using Eclipse Juno as IDE running on Java SDK 7. It was working fine a few days before. It still works ok, but when pressing the dot (period) button, it closes down.

My laptop configuration:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- RAM: 2GB
- Graphics: AMD E1

Upon searching for a solution, I found options like:

- set the value in Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler to Java 1.6
- set `"-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla"` in `.ini` file

None of the above worked. It is quite annoying. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Please post a crash log if applicable or further information. This is likely not enough information to go on.

Comment: Formatted question to make it easy to spot configuration and solution attempts

Comment: After it crashes, please, check workspaceLocation/.metadata/*.log and post the latest exception here (check for exception's time to match the crash to ensure it is a relevant one). Feel free to edit your question by putting "Update" header and the exception below it.